# How do I make an object go from point A to point B but point B is moving? C++

Tags: c++

I am making a simple game to help me learn basic c++ code. I want to make a zombie able to follow / chase the player in a 2d snake-like environment. Though I haven't been able to find a way to get this to work yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

const int width = 60;
const int height = 20;
int x, y;
int zombX, zombY;

void Setup()
{
x = width / 2;
y = height / 2;
zombX = rand() % width;
zombY = rand() % height;
}

void Draw()
{
system("cls");                                       
for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
    cout << "*";                                    
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //i = height
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
            cout << "*";
        if (i == y && j == x)
            cout << "I";
        else if (i == zombY && j == zombX)
            cout << "Z";
        else
        {
            bool print = false;
            if (!print)
                cout << " ";
        }

        if (j == width - 1)
            cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
    cout << "*";
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Extremely broad question. Please specify your exact problem and show us what you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main loop, before you call `Draw` you change the position of the zombie. Make its position (on X or Y axis) one step closer to the player.

This can easily be done since you know the current position of the player. If zombie-X is higher than player-X, then decrease zombie-X. Or if opposite then increase zombie-X. Same with the Y position.

To not make the zombie just walk up-down (or left-right) you adjust the X position of the zombie every second time in the main loop, and the Y position every second time. Or you could select X or Y randomly.

In short, your "point B" is *always* the players current position.

Comment: How would I adjust the x position every second time?

Comment: @Kamarkios `if (some_counter++ % 2 == 0) change_x_pos(); else change_y_pos();`

Comment: Do you know how I would go about making a spawn system for the zombies? Like, if I wanted to add 2 more zombies with the same movement, different x and y locations how would I do that? If there is a link to a book or video I could watch that could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your game logic should be something like this.

```
Setup();
do
{
 Draw();
 Delay();
 Update();
}while(!bIsEnd);
```

Update is where you update your objects position.
Including check for any human input (keyboard/mouse) and
move objects based on it.
Some objects are moved automatically (AI)

This function where you should put your update position's logic(I & Z) 
I assume 'I' is human controlled and 'Z' is computer controlled (AI). 
For 'I' you can get input from keyboard using [_getch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) function  and do switch case. 
For 'Z', because this is a game you should make it challenging. 
Not too stupid or too smart. 
You can give random for movement (X or Y direction).
For Every 4 update calls, you define its direction by calculating from your
'I' and 'Z' position.

```
if(X > ZombX) 
  ZombX += random(2);
else
  ZombX -= random(2);
if(Y > ZombY)
  ZombY += random(2);
else
 ZombY -= random(2);
```

4 update calls is just example. You may use another constant or develop a a new logic.

if (X == ZombX && Y == ZombY) , you set bIsEnd.